# xamarin.forms master detail menu page from both sides

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a master detail page that displays from the left. But Id also like this exact feature coming from the other side. so TWO side drawer menus.

It is possible to show the page on the other side by doing:

```
<MasterDetailPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Khaled.Views.MainMenu"
    Title="Title"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
    x:Class="Khaled.Views.MainMenu.Page_MainMenu">
```

But this doesnt copy the page, it just shows it on the other side. I want TWO on each side (with the option to swipe it open)
Anyone got any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Like `Mina Fawzy` said, `MasterDetailPage` is obsolete as of version 5.0.0. Please use `FlyoutPage` instead.

You would be better to use the single side. When you set the `VisualElement.FlowDirection` property to RTL OR LTR, it would change the direction in which the UI elements on the page are scanned by the eye.

**Left to Right:**

[image]

**Right to Left:**

[image]

That's why we could not set both sides at the same time. But we could change the FlowDirection property at runtime through we do not suggest to do that. Changing this value at runtime causes an expensive layout process that will affect performance.

The way used to change the FlowDirection to `RightToLeft`.

**Android:**

Xaml:

```
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.FlyoutPage1"
         FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:App1">
  ......
</FlyoutPage>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:label="App1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
```

**iOS:**

For ios, refer to the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left#ios

Comment: This actually works quite well, However, the listener to the slide effect only works on that side, where the last flow direction was set. How can I make the listener work on both sides?

Comment: i have another issue: when i open the drawer from the other side, the flow direction also changes on the whole page content. how can i stop it from happening?

Comment: You could not do that. The two things are bound.  If you want to open the drawer from the other side, the flow direction also changes on the whole page content.

Answer (score 0):

you can create icons in the top right and top left (hamburger menu)
and then control them by code.

`FlowDirection` --> this controls the direction of the menu
`IsPresented` --> flag to open or close menu by code

when you want to present the right menu

```
FlowDirection = "RightToLeft";  
IsPresented= true;
```

for the left

```
FlowDirection = "LeftToRight";
    IsPresented= true;
```

**Recommendation**

MasterDetails are deprecated use `FlyoutPage`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: This actually works quite well, However, the listener to the slide effect only works on that side, where the last flow direction was set. How can I make the listener work on both sides?

Comment: i have another issue: when i open the drawer from the other side, the flow direction also changes on the whole page content. how can i stop it from happening?

Comment: you can change FlowDirection in runtime before opening the menu by this IsPresented